# Magento 2 : Add, read and delete custom key value pairs in Redis

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.3.4, redis

I want to implement a custom cache for a feature and want to store key-value pairs in Redis for the same. Is there some standard class/implementation which I should follow to go about accomplishing this?